# Reloading DataTables AJAX with Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4

**UPDATED**

The idea is so that when the modal opens to create or edit a user, the validation is made and once you click submit, it'll hide the modal and refresh the datattable already on the page, which is using jquery datattabes.net. The problem is after clicking submit, nothing happens.

Here's the info I've been using to guide myself:

http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/ajax-submit/

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

var oTable = $('#dataTable-users').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "{{ URL::to('usuarios.tabla') }}"
})

$('.editUser')
    .bootstrapValidator( {
        excluded: [':disabled', ':hidden', ':not(:visible)'],
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            first_name: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'El nombre es obligatorio y no puede quedar vacio.'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        max: 100,
                        message: 'El nombre no puede tener menos de 3 letras.'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
                        message: 'El nombre solo puede contener letras y espacios.'
                    }
                }
            },

            last_name: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'El apellido es obligatorio y no puede quedar vacio.'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        max: 100,
                        message: 'El apellido no puede tener menos de 3 letras.'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
                        message: 'El apellido solo puede contener letras y espacios.'
                    }
                }
            },

            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'El email es obligatorio y no puede quedar vacio.'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'La información ingresada no corresponde a un email.'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(e.target),                        // The form instance
            bv    = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');   // BootstrapValidator instance

        // Use Ajax to submit form data
        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result) {
            $('#user-modal').modal("hide");
            oTable.ajax.url( 'http://localhost:8888/adp/usuarios.tabla' ).load();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And the view

```
@foreach($users as $key => $value)
<div class="modal fade edit-user-modal{{ $value->id }} user-modal" id="user-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Editando usuario <strong>{{ $value->username }}</strong></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                {{ Form::model($value, array('route' => array('usuarios.update', $value->id), 'class' => 'editUser', 'method' => 'PUT')) }}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('password', 'Contraseña') }}
                    {{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('first_name', 'Nombres') }}
                    {{ Form::text('first_name', Input::old('first_name'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('last_name', 'Apellidos') }}
                    {{ Form::text('last_name', Input::old('last_name'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
                    {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                &nbsp;
                {{ Form::token() }}
                {{ Form::submit('Editar usuario', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Any error messages? What issues are you experiencing?

Comment: The AJAX table won't reload, and I got no way of hiding the modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the following lines as indicated below. You do not need to trigger the `submit` event - it's already occurred - and you do not need to `submit` the form at that point - that's what `$.post()` is meant for. And since you do not have an ajax UUR in the original configuration, you do need to specify one.

```
    form.submit(); // PLUS 'form' is not defined.
    oTable.ajax.reload();
```

New code:

```
oTable.ajax.url( 'url-to-updated-json-data' ).load();
```

**NOTE:**  Since you do not use `result` anywhere, you don't care what's returned; therefore you do not need to set `json` dataType.

**Update:**

Thanks for provide more code that give a much better context of the issue you're having. There're a few points I would like to raise.

1. The **reason your modal wont close is, you're using duplicate ids**. How would jquery know which `#user-modal` you want to target? Use a class instead. In your `@foreach` code use `class="user-modal"` instead of `id="user-modal"`; same goes for any other IDs in that block. You can grab the correct modal in the `submit` handler, using `$(this).closest('.user-modal')` or `$(e.target).closest('.user-modal')`.
2. Not critical but in **Laravel 4** you don't need to `{{ Form::token() }}` as it is called automatically via `{{ Form::open(....) }}`.

Comment: Does not update the UI table or DB table? You should be able to hide the modal by calling `$('modal-selector').modal('hide');`.

Comment: For some reason, after pressing submit on the form (which is inside the modal) it updates the table if the validation passes, but it won't hide the modal or update the datatable with ajax. The code I'm running is the one I just updated on the main post, much more organised.

Comment: Awesome! Works now! Only thing left to fix is updating the table once the modal hides. Any ideas why the current code wouldn't work? The oTable variable is created and is working, the table does display and allows me to edit each user individually with what I've developed, but it won't update on the submit.

Comment: Is an ajax call made to `http://localhost:8888/adp/usuarios.tabla`? What kind of data is returned? Got a sample?

Comment: If this answer has helped you, don't forget to accept it as the answer.

Comment: It returns the datatable data as json. It's actually the one you see loading the datatable at the beginning of the script. Such as "sAjaxSource": "{{ URL::to('usuarios.tabla') }}"

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Laravel package `Yajra` DataTable (https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables),

```
window.LaravelDataTables["user-table"].ajax.reload();
```

I hope this will helpful someone.

Answer (score 4):

None above worked for me.
I used **yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle : 9.11** in my laravel project and
**DataTables 1.10.16 and  DataTables Bootstrap 3 integration**

In my case only this worked.

```
$('.data-table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to let know those who use Bootstrap validator that in order to refresh the Ajax table you after clicking the submit button must use the following code, which isn't correctly mentioned under the documentation.

```
oTable.api().ajax.reload();
```

The .api() is required in order for it to work as I had initially mentioned.